# Separate a long equation in an array environment

Tags: arrays

I wanna to separate a long equation in an `array` environment, as it shows in the following graph: Place the right part of `||` to the below of `=`.

[image]

CODE:

```
\[ \Delta P_k^{ij} \; \text{is} \; \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \text{known} & \text{if $\Delta P_k=\bf{0}$}\\
    \bf{0} & \text{if $\Delta P_k=-(I-K_k^i H_k^i)( F_{k-1} P^{ij}_{k-1} F^T_{k-1}+Q_{k-1})(I-K_k^j H_k^j)^T$ }\\
    \text{unknown} & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{array} \right.\]
```

Comment: use the `aligned` environment from `amsmath` with the `[t]` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an extension to Barbaras comment

Note I've replaced `\bf` as (1) it should not be used, (2) does not take arguments

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[ \Delta P_k^{ij} \; \text{is} 
\begin{cases}
    \text{known} & \text{if $\Delta P_k=\mathbf{0}$}\\
    \mathbf{0} & \text{if $
      \begin{aligned}[t]
        \Delta P_k={}&-(I-K_k^i H_k^i)( F_{k-1} P^{ij}_{k-1}
        F^T_{k-1}
        \\
        &+Q_{k-1})(I-K_k^j H_k^j)^T
      \end{aligned}
      $ }\\
    \text{unknown} & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
   \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `{}` after `F_{k-1}` and `Q_{k-1}` would lower the subscript terms, making them line up with the other subscript terms in the formula.

Comment: Perhaps writing `(K^i_k H^i_k - I)' reads nicer than '-(I  - K^i_k H^i_k)'. It also simplifies the expression slightly.  I'd also add one or two quads before the plus symbol or introduce a nicer break, e.g. at the multiplication level.

Comment: Feel free to update the answer